# Django: STATIC_* and MEDIA_* all identical, but app still runs in production

Tags: django

I'm currently working on a Django 1.3 app where both `MEDIA_ROOT` and `STATIC_ROOT` are identical, and `MEDIA_URL` and `STATIC_URL` are identical.

This (somehow) runs on the production server, but locally when I call `manage.py runserver` I get an `ImproperlyConfigured` exception and can only run the application when I override the settings so that `MEDIA_*` is different from `STATIC_*` (`DEBUG=False` just gives a 500). This is what I would expect to happen ([as per documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/)), and so I don't understand how they can get it working in Production.

The original developer of the application has moved on so I can't ask any questions as how they've managed to get this to work. Is there a known method of circumventing Django's static and media file separation?

Comment: Can you confirm production settings? Go to production, open a manage.py shell, and pull `from django.conf import settings;print(settings.STATIC_URL, settings.MEDIA_URL)` -- perhaps some code is modifying the settings dynamically after detecting environment? Who knows... also try `manage.py runserver` on the production machine - maybe someone hacked into that django install. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the comment Yuji, I tried all of the above and it was quite happily reporting identical STATIC* and MEDIA*, DEBUG=False. I downloaded the django install and PyPi's django (same version) and diff'ed them, and they are identical. The answer can't be too far away :)

Comment: So that means runserver fails on remote as it does on local?

Comment: Runserver works fine on the remote (unlike local), still haven't worked out what's going on

Comment: Interestingly if I run a manage.py shell and manually call `django.contrib.staticfiles.utils.check_settings()` it raises ImproperlyConfigured, but doesn't appear to fail/get called when running `runserver`.

Comment: Can you import django on remote and check django.__file__ ? Perhaps it's importing a modified django or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a great answer as it's so specific, but the answer was that they just never run the application with `DEBUG=True` (runserver will run happily with `DEBUG=False` and incorrect `MEDIA_*` and `STATIC_*` settings). There was no silver bullet, the application appears to be debugged using the error log created by mod_wsgi (no logging in place). I assume that this also how the development environment was set up.

The application is also notable for being run whilst not being on the `PYTHONPATH`, and having all of its apps in a separate folder in another part of the filesystem. This was discovered when adding a new application to the folder containing `manage.py` and having import errors for the new application. I think this was so that multiple django installations could use the same set of apps.

Thanks to Yuji for his help .